# Let $G = (V,E)$ be a graph with $|V|=n$ and $|E|=e$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a graph with $|V|=n$ and $|E|=e$.
Let $M = \max_{v\in V} \deg(v)$ and $m = \min_{v\in V} \deg(v)$.
Show that $m\leq 2e/n \leq M$.

How do I approach this problem? I am especially confused by $m\leq 2e/n \leq M$.

Comment: In a graph $G$, the sum of the degrees of the vertices is equal to
twice the number of edges. Are you familiar with this theorem?

Comment: No I have not, how does this apply to the $2eln$?

Comment: You can also write that as $mn \leq 2e \leq Mn$. Think about this last inequality for a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be familiar with this theorem:

> In a graph $G$, the sum of the degrees of the vertices is equal to
>   twice the number of edges.

With your notation this would mean that
$$\sum_{v \in V} \deg(v)=2e.\tag{1}$$
Now, for every $v \in V$ we have that   $\deg(v)$ can be any number such that 
 $$ m \leq \deg(v) \leq M. \tag{2}$$
So, suppose $V=\{ v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\} $ is your vertex set. As a consequence of $(2)$ we have that
$$\underbrace{m+m+\ldots+m}_{n \text{ times}} \leq \deg{(v_1)+\deg{(v_2)}+\ldots+\deg{(v_n)}}\leq \underbrace{M + M + \ldots+M}_{n \text{ times}}$$
Notice the LHS reduces to $m \cdot n$, RHS reduces to $M\cdot n$ and because of the first theorem we have that $\deg{(v_1)+\deg{(v_2)}+\ldots+\deg{(v_n)}} = 2e$. Thus

$$m\cdot n \leq 2e \leq M \cdot n \implies m\leq \frac{2e}{n} \leq M.$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $2e/n$ is the average degree. The result is immediate from this observation.